# Logging in AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I've having issues getting logging set up properly on my development app server (launched from Eclipse).  I have the correct logging.properties location in my appengine-web.xml, and the most global parameter is working:

```
.level=ALL
```

If I change that to `INFO` everything quiets down and all is good.  But trying to add any sort of override for my packages appears to do nothing at all:

```
.level=ALL
com.company.level=INFO
```

(I am using my real package name, using the above as an example)

When I try to a full package path such as `com.company.user.level` or even a class name such as `com.company.user.User.level` I still get no change.  I've also tried moving my entry above and below the `.level` statement with no luck.  As a last resort I tried taking out `.level` altogether, but that resulted in no change to my custom class logging.

Between each change I fully stop and restart the development appserver to make sure the file is re-read.  Again, if I change `.level` I see a change in logging level output, but nothing else works.  I'm stumped?  Any suggestions?

*AppEngine SDK: 1.9.17 (1.9.18 is the latest as of this writing but there is nothing to indicate this would be fixed in the change logs).*

Thanks!!

**UPDATE (Solution)**
Thanks to @farrellmr below!!

I was doing the following:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("MyClass"); // wrong
```

When I should have been doing:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()); // correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your logger as -

```
package test;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Then you can define your package log configuration as -

```
test.level = INFO
```

Comment: ZOMG!!!  You would think that after years of programming I would figure out the simple stuff on my own...NOPE!!  I'm a complete moron.

I was doing the following:

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("MyClass");

Which of course doesn't have the package name.  Seriously, I need to put the keyboard down and have a beer or something.  Thank you @farrelmr!!!